# What is the difference between LD_LIBRARY_PATH and -L at link time?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I'm having problems with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at **link** time (this question has nothing to do with run time).

The link line looks like this when I run make (this is a Linux system using g++ version 4.1.x):

```
g++ a.o b.o c.o -o myapp \
 -L/long/path/to/libs/ \
 -L/another/long/path/ \
 -labc -ldef -lghi
```

The `-l` options reference shared libraries (e.g., libabc.so) which exist in the directories specified by the `-L` options.  Those directories also appear in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  With that configuration, the link is successful, and I can run the application.

If I remove the directories from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then I get a single error line such as:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -labc
```

On the other hand, if I remove the directories from the list of `-L` options, then I get many warnings such as:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libabc.so, needed by /long/path/to/libs/libxyz.so,
    not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

and then many more errors, such as:

```
/long/path/to/libs/libdef.so: undefined reference to `Foo::Bar<Baz>::junk(Fred*)'
```

Can someone explain the difference between `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `-L`?  I would like to understand this stuff in depth, so references are greatly appreciated!

Also, what do I have to add to the link line to avoid using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

**EDIT:** When directories were missing from `-L`, the compiler suggested to "try using -rpath or -rpath-link".  I don't think I've ever seen those options in a makefile before.  Have you?  Not sure if that would help the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` problem though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The settings of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has the highest precedence, so when it is set, the set of  directories mentioned by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are searched first even before the standard set
of directories. So in your case setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is influencing the lookup of
the libraries mentioned with `-l` option. Without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` some of the dependencies
might have been resolved from the standard set of directories.

Though setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` help with debugging and to try out a newer version of
a library its usage in the general development environment setup and deployment is considered bad.

Also refer [this HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) from Linux Documentation for more details on Shared Libraries

Comment: Stating that something is "bad" without saying why it is, this is definitely a "bad" thing (and I can say why it is).

Comment: While your answer is correct, I think to answer the question it is important to emphasize that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` affects runtime search paths (and also link time search paths) while `-L` or `LDFLAGS` affect the link time search paths.

Answer (score 35):

There are two answers to this question, part of the answer lies in the compile-time linking (i.e `gcc -lfoo -L/usr/lib` ... which in turn calls `ld`), and run-time linker lookups.

When you compile your program, the compiler checks syntax, and then the linker ensures that the symbols required for execution exist (i.e variables / methods / etc), among other things. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, as has been noted, has the side-effect of altering the way `gcc`/`ld` behave as well as the way the the run-time linker behaves by modifying the search path.

When you run your program, the run-time linker actually fetches the shared libraries (on disk or from memory if possible), and loads in the shared symbols / code / etc. Again, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` affects this search path implicitly (sometimes not a good thing, as has been mentioned.)

The correct fix for this without using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on most Linux systems is to add the path that contains your shared libraries to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or in some distributions, create a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` with the path in it) and run `ldconfig` (`/sbin/ldconfig` as root) to update the runtime linker bindings cache.

Example on Debian:

```
jewart@dorfl:~$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usrlocal.conf 
/usr/local/lib
```

Then when the program is executed, the run-time linker will look in those directories for libraries that your binary has been linked against.

If you want to know what libraries the run-time linker knows about, you can use:

```
jewart@dorfl:~$ ldconfig -v 

/usr/lib:
libbfd-2.18.0.20080103.so -> libbfd-2.18.0.20080103.so
libkdb5.so.4 -> libkdb5.so.4.0
libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0
```

And, if you want to know what libraries a binary is linked against, you can use `ldd` like such, which will tell you which library your runtime linker is going to choose:

```
jewart@dorfl:~$ ldd /bin/ls
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffda1ff000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5d2149b000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f5d2127f000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f5d21077000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5d20d23000)
```

Comment: +1, good concise description of how linking & loading works.  ld.so.conf seems like it could have some of the same problems as LD_LIBRARY_PATH, although it wouldn't impact link-time, only run-time -- it's mentioned here as a <href="http://xahlee.org/UnixResource%5Fdir/%5F/ldpath.html">half-hearted attempt to improve things</a>.

Comment: However, I still don't understand why the absence of LD_LIBRARY_PATH prevents the link.  Editing ld.so.conf is not an option.  If it were, would it even address the problem I have at link-time when I remove directories from LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: The way I read your original post is the following:

Compilation with -L/path/to/lib1 -L/path/to/lib2and3 -llib1 -llib2 -llib3 works, but execution fails unless LD_LIBRARY_PATH has /path/to/lib{1,2and3} in it. 

If linking at compile time is failing, then something is awry with your -L paths... Can you post the actual compilation command that fails?

Comment: No... it's **link** that fails unless LD_LIBRARY_PATH has /path/to/lib{1,2,3} in it.  I will check for discrepancies between the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and what is specified by -L.  Unfortunately I cannot post the compilation command.  Regardless of what LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to, it does not affect what gets spit out by make as the compilation/link command.

Comment: Correct, you won't see it in the output, just whatever the Makefile has as written by a human or computed by autotools. Is it possible that the error you're seeing is actually earlier than you compiling your specific binary? Maybe from a dependency that's trying to compile (ala autoconf's tests for the existence of a library), and failing because your libabc.so is not in a standard location (and not explicitly specified via -L)? That would be a scenario where compilation / autoconf works with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set...

Comment: what do you mean when you say "LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as has been noted, has the side-effect of altering the way gcc/ld behave as well as the way the the run-time linker behaves by modifying the search path."

Comment: Does linker use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at compilation time?

Answer (score 8):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is intended for finding shared libraries when running an application.  It is a side effect that it's impacting your link, and you should not rely on that.

> As an often unwanted side effect,
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH will also be searched
> at link (ld) stage after directories
> specified with -L (also if no -L flag
> is given).

[Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html)

Comment: I agree it's a side effect, and I would prefer not to rely on it.  But I'm not sure where to put the directories instead of in LD_LIBRARY_PATH -- because just having them in -L apparently isn't good enough.  Thanks for the link -- good reading!

Comment: what is the side effect that causes LD_LIBRARY_PATH to malfunction and makes us want to add the paths in /etc/ld.so.conf ????

Comment: @VasanthNagKV If I had to guess I would say because environment variables are less reliable than having your loader explicitly load a file with the intended paths. For example you might be running the process from a different user that is using a different environment. Having the paths in the file makes the execution more deterministic I guess because it doesn't depend on the runtime environment.

Answer (score 4):

If I were to guess, I would say that the linker is falling back to using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to resolve libraries that your direct links (e.g., `libabc.so`, `libdef.so`, and `libghi.so`) are dynamically linked against.  Looking at the manual page for `ld`, it looks like linking against an `.so` that was built using `-rpath` would affect how the lookup of dynamically bound symbols works.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the man for g++, I found out that `-lxxxxx` option is looking for `libxxxxx.a` in the provided path `-L` so at linking time , only `.a` file will be loaded. At run time, if a library is missing then only library as shared object so .so will be loaded and then it will look in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. On the executable I am working on , I see that in some library directory, there is the version `libxxxx.a` and `libxxxx.so` so I think it means that the library can be linked at the linking time or linked at the run time as a shared object.

If a library exists only as shared object , then it means that the library directory path needs to be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be found at the run time. 
If a library exists only as an archived so .a , then it means that it needs to be linked at the  build of the executable and then -L directorypath and `-lxxxxx` need to be provided at g++ at compilation time .

This is my understanding .... and at least it is in line with your observations