# Step into libcurl functions while debugging a program that uses the library with gdb

Tags: gcc, gdb, libcurl

I am trying to debug a program that uses libcurl library and step into the library functions with gdb.

What I've tried so far. I downloaded curl's sources

```
git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
```

and built it with autotools (following this post `https://askubuntu.com/questions/27677/cannot-find-install-sh-install-sh-or-shtool-in-ac-aux`):

```
libtoolize --force
aclocal
autoheader
automake --force-missing --add-missing
autoconf
```

and configured like:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/curl --enable-debug
```

Finally

```
make
make install
```

Now I can debug the `curl` program generated with `gdb $HOME/curl/bin/curl`.

What I want though is to debug my own program and be able to debug it accessing the libcurl internals.
So I tried with this simple example https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/examples/get , which I built with

```
gcc -g example.c -L$HOME/curl/lib -lcurl
```

It looks like it is linking the sources I've just built because

```
gcc -g -Wl,--verbose example.c -L${HOME}/curl/lib -lcurl | grep "libcurl.so succeeded"
```

gives

```
attempt to open /home/user//curl/lib/libcurl.so succeeded
```

But when I debug the program `gdb ./a.out` I am unable to jump into the libcurl functions.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the correct `libcurl.so` loaded by the running program? What does `info shared` say?

Comment: It is loading `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so` . So the line `gcc -g example.c -L$HOME/curl/lib -lcurl` is not doing what I want, right?

Comment: Sure, it is linking with the library you want. But if you want it also to be used by the running program, you can for example set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1904990/1983398) for further details.

Comment: Adding the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I debug the program gdb ./a.out I am unable to jump into the libcurl functions.

This is because the library used at (static) link time and the library used at runtime don't necessarily match, and don't match in your case.

To make them match, you need to tell the runtime loader where to look for `libcurl.so`.

You can do this with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/curl/lib`, but that is *suboptimal* -- this environment variable affects *all* programs, and may cause them to crash.

A *better* way is to set the `RUNPATH` of the particular program:

```
gcc -g example.c -L$HOME/curl/lib -lcurl -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/curl/lib
```

With above, the `a.out` executable linked against `$HOME/curl/lib/libcurl.so` will *also* use that library at runtime, while other binaries will continue to use the system `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so`.